# Podman build can't find app.py in the specified folder

Tags: python, podman

I am at my first hands on practice with trying to deploy my model on GCloud and I am using podman. When I try to build the container with `podman  build -t default-service-fastpai:latest .` , I get an error at STEP 6/9

```
STEP 6/8: COPY app /
Error: building at STEP "COPY app /": checking on sources under "Documents/Projects/Pred_default/app": copier: stat: "/app": no such file or directory
```

The folder is formatted as follows:

```
└── Pred_default
    └── app
        └── Containerfile
        └── app.py
        └── app_test.py
        └── lgb_credit_model.pkl
        └── lgb_es_model.pkl
        └── measure_response.py
        └── requirements.txt
    └── .gitignore
    └── LICENSE.md
    └── README.md
    └── credit_predict.ipynb
    └── requirements.txt
```

And this is the Containerfile. I am not sure what is going wrong, the app.py is right there, why can't podman see it?

```
FROM python:3.10-slim

RUN mkdir /app
# Set the working directory
WORKDIR /app

# Copy the requirements file into the container
COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt

# Install the required packages
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

# Copy the application code into the container
COPY app /
# COPY ["lgb_credit_model.pkl", "lgb_es_model.pkl" "app.py", "./"] 

# Expose the app port
EXPOSE 80

# Run command
CMD ["uvicorn", "app:app", "--host", "0.0.0.0", "--port", "80"]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the error you shared and your Containerfile, it seems the issue is due to the fact that the `COPY` command in your Containerfile cannot find the `app` directory within the specified context. It tries to copy the `app` directory to the root directory (`/`) of the container, but it seems like you might want to copy it into the `/app` directory you created inside the container.

Change the `COPY` command in your Containerfile from:

```
COPY app /
```

to:

```
COPY app/ /app/
```

This should correctly copy the contents of your local `app` directory into the `/app` directory inside the container.

Also make sure to run the `podman build` command from the `Pred_default` directory, where the `app` directory is located.

Comment: Thank you! This worked, effectively built the container. I am just not sure why when i try to run `gcloud auth configure-docker europe-west2-docker.pkg.dev` it doesn't work. Maybe because I am using podman instead of docker